# Calculating determinant with different numbers on diagonal and x everywhere else

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I'm having troubles solving the following determinant:

$$\left|
  \begin{array}{cccc}
    a_1 & x & \ldots & x \\
   x & a_2 & \ldots & \vdots \\
    \vdots & \ldots & \ddots & x \\
    x & \ldots & x & a_n \\
  \end{array}
\right|$$

I have tried coming up with recurrent formula, but there's always one lingering row and column. I also tried finding values of x for which determinant is 0, hoping I could get a nice polynomial solution, with no luck.

By subtracting first row from every other I get somewhat nicer result, but there's still that one row/column which I can't solve. If all other columns are added to the first one and then I subtract the first row, then the column doesn't depend on x anymore, but I haven't found 1..n much more useful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate the following determinants (all ones, minus $I$)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84206/how-to-calculate-the-following-determinants-all-ones-minus-i)

Comment: @amd the diagonal entries are different here.

Comment: Even though the question is different, the answer is similar; however, I cannot pull out any factor after adding everything to the first row, since I have different numbers on the diagonal (I have $$a_i+(n-1)x$$ instead of $$a+(n-1)x$$)

Comment: Your matrix is $D + xk^T k$, where $D$ is the diagonal matrix $\operatorname{diag}\left(a_1-x,a_2-x,\ldots,a_n-x\right)$, and $k$ is the row vector $\left(1,1,\ldots,1\right)$. Now, use the fact so inventively and unambiguously christened the "matrix determinant lemma" ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma#Statement , see the version without the invertibility requirement).

Comment: @darij grinberg You should give your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 8):

As requested, here is the answer I hinted to in my comment:

> **Theorem 1.** Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a commutative ring.
> Let $a_{1},a_{2},\ldots,a_{n}$ be $n$ elements of $\mathbb{K}$. Let
> $x\in\mathbb{K}$. Let $A\in\mathbb{K}^{n\times n}$ be the $n\times n$-matrix
> $\left(
> \begin{array}
> [c]{ccccc}
> a_{1} & x & x & \cdots & x\\
> x & a_{2} & x & \cdots & x\\
> x & x & a_{3} & \cdots & x\\
> \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
> x & x & x & \cdots & a_{n}
> \end{array}
> \right)  $ (this is the $n\times n$-matrix whose diagonal entries are
> $a_{1},a_{2},\ldots,a_{n}$, while all its other entries are $x$). For each
> $i\in\left\{  1,2,\ldots,n\right\}  $, set $b_{i}=\prod\limits_{\substack{k\in
> \left\{  1,2,\ldots,n\right\}  ;\\k\neq i}}\left(  a_{k}-x\right)  $.  Then,

> $\det A=\prod\limits_{i=1}^{n}\left(  a_{i}-x\right)  +x\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}b_{i}$.

To prove this, we recall the following fact (known as the [matrix determinant
lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma#Statement),
although it would not surprise me if it has several contenders for its rather
generic name):

> **Lemma 2.** Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a commutative ring. Let
> $\mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{K}^{n\times n}$ be an $n\times n$-matrix. Let
> $\mathbf{u}\in\mathbb{K}^{n\times1}$ and $\mathbf{v}\in\mathbb{K}^{n\times1}$
> be two column vectors. Then,

> $\det\left(  \mathbf{A}+\mathbf{uv}^{T}\right)  =\det\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{v}
> ^{T}\left(  \operatorname*{adj}\mathbf{A}\right)  \mathbf{u}$.

(Here and in the following, $\operatorname*{adj}\mathbf{A}$ denotes the
adjugate of $\mathbf{A}$.)

See [Matrix determinant lemma with adjugate matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1514408) for a proof of Lemma 2.

We also shall use the following simple fact:

> **Lemma 3.** Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a commutative ring. Let
> $a_{1},a_{2},\ldots,a_{n}$ be $n$ elements of $\mathbb{K}$. For each
> $i\in\left\{  1,2,\ldots,n\right\}  $, set $b_{i}=\prod\limits_{\substack{k\in
> \left\{  1,2,\ldots,n\right\}  ;\\k\neq i}}a_{k}$. Then,

> $\operatorname*{adj}\left(  \left(  a_{i}\delta_{i,j}\right)  _{1\leq i\leq
> n,\ 1\leq j\leq n}\right)  =\left(  b_{i}\delta_{i,j}\right)  _{1\leq i\leq
> n,\ 1\leq j\leq n}$.

(Here, as usual, $\delta_{i,j}$ is the Kronecker delta of $i$ and $j$.)

*Proof of Lemma 3.* Lemma 3 simply says that the adjugate of the diagonal
matrix with diagonal entries $a_{1},a_{2},\ldots,a_{n}$ is the diagonal matrix
with diagonal entries $b_{1},b_{2},\ldots,b_{n}$. This is easy to check (since
each $\left(  n-1\right)  \times\left(  n-1\right)  $-submatrix of a diagonal
matrix either is a diagonal matrix itself, or has a zero row).

Now, we can prove Theorem 1:

*Proof of Theorem 1.* Let $\mathbf{A}$ be the $n\times n$-matrix $\left(
\left(  a_{i}-x\right)  \delta_{i,j}\right)  _{1\leq i\leq n,\ 1\leq j\leq n}
$. (This $\mathbf{A}$ is the diagonal matrix with diagonal entries
$a_{1}-x,a_{2}-x,\ldots,a_{n}-x$). Thus, $\det\mathbf{A}=\prod\limits_{i=1}
^{n}\left(  a_{i}-x\right)  $ (since the determinant of a diagonal matrix is
the product of its diagonal entries). But Lemma 3 (applied to $a_{1}
-x,a_{2}-x,\ldots,a_{n}-x$ instead of $a_{1},a_{2},\ldots,a_{n}$) yields that

$\operatorname*{adj}\left(  \left(  \left(  a_{i}-x\right)  \delta
_{i,j}\right)  _{1\leq i\leq n,\ 1\leq j\leq n}\right)  =\left(  b_{i}
\delta_{i,j}\right)  _{1\leq i\leq n,\ 1\leq j\leq n}$.

Since $\left(  \left(  a_{i}-x\right)  \delta_{i,j}\right)  _{1\leq i\leq
n,\ 1\leq j\leq n}=\mathbf{A}$, this rewrites as

$\operatorname*{adj}\mathbf{A}=\left(  b_{i}\delta_{i,j}\right)
_{1\leq i\leq n,\ 1\leq j\leq n}$.

Let $\mathbf{v}\in\mathbb{K}^{n\times1}$ be the column vector $\left(
1,1,\ldots,1\right)  ^{T}$. Then, $\mathbf{vv}^{T}=\left(  1\right)  _{1\leq
i\leq n,\ 1\leq j\leq n}$, so that $x\mathbf{vv}^{T}=x\left(  1\right)
_{1\leq i\leq n,\ 1\leq j\leq n}=\left(  x\right)  _{1\leq i\leq n,\ 1\leq
j\leq n}$. Hence, it is easy to see that $A=\mathbf{A}+x\mathbf{vv}^{T}$.

Recall that $\mathbf{v}=\left(  1,1,\ldots,1\right)  ^{T}$. Thus, for every
$n\times n$-matrix $B$, we have

$\mathbf{v}^{T}B\mathbf{v}=\left(  \text{the sum of all entries of }B\right)
$.

Applying this to $B=\left(  b_{i}\delta_{i,j}\right)  _{1\leq i\leq n,\ 1\leq
j\leq n}$, we obtain

$\mathbf{v}^{T}\left(  b_{i}\delta_{i,j}\right)  _{1\leq i\leq n,\ 1\leq j\leq
n}\mathbf{v}$

$=\left(  \text{the sum of all entries of }\left(  b_{i}\delta_{i,j}\right)
_{1\leq i\leq n,\ 1\leq j\leq n}\right)  $

$=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}b_{i}\delta_{i,j}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}b_{i}
\underbrace{\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}\delta_{i,j}}_{=1}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}b_{i}$.

But from $A=\mathbf{A}+x\mathbf{vv}^{T}$, we obtain

$\det A=\det\left(  \mathbf{A}+x\mathbf{vv}^{T}\right)  $

$=\underbrace{\det\mathbf{A}}_{=\prod\limits_{i=1}^{n}\left(  a_{i}-x\right)
}+\mathbf{v}^{T}\underbrace{\left(  \operatorname*{adj}\mathbf{A}\right)
}_{=\left(  b_{i}\delta_{i,j}\right)  _{1\leq i\leq n,\ 1\leq j\leq n}
}x\mathbf{v}$

(by Lemma 2, applied to $\mathbf{u}=x\mathbf{v}$)

$=\prod\limits_{i=1}^{n}\left(  a_{i}-x\right)  +\mathbf{v}^{T}\left(  b_{i}
\delta_{i,j}\right)  _{1\leq i\leq n,\ 1\leq j\leq n}x\mathbf{v}$

$=\prod\limits_{i=1}^{n}\left(  a_{i}-x\right)  +x\underbrace{\mathbf{v}^{T}\left(
b_{i}\delta_{i,j}\right)  _{1\leq i\leq n,\ 1\leq j\leq n}\mathbf{v}}
_{=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}b_{i}}$

$=\prod\limits_{i=1}^{n}\left(  a_{i}-x\right)  +x\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}b_{i}$.

This proves Theorem 1.

Two other proofs of Theorem 1 can be found in [my *Math 235 Fall 2023, Worksheet 10*](https://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/%7Egrinberg/t/23f/lec10.pdf) as solutions to Exercise 10.3.1. (The second solution requires $\mathbb{K}$ to be a field, but this case yields the general case because the claim is a universal identity between polynomials with integer coefficients.)

Comment: @becko: Your answer uses division, which in general requires a Zariski-density-style argument; I made the conscious choice to avoid that in my post. Other than this, your answer is indeed simpler.

Comment: This answer looks overly complicated. The OP question can be answered more directly, please see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2931799/10063. Also (as in your comment), the result can be computed simply applying the Sherman Morrison formula.

Comment: @becko: The Sherman-Morrison uses division, too :)

Comment: I meant for real matrices. I think your proof is much more ambitious.

Comment: are the $a_i$ allowed to be all equal to each other?

Comment: @Girardi sure, they are.

Answer (score 2):

A related problem for future reference to someone looking for this answer:

When all $a_i=a$, you have the matrix

$$
A_{n\times n}=\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
a&x&\dots&x\\
x&a&\dots&x\\
\vdots&&\ddots&\vdots\\
x&x&\dots&a\\
\end{array}\right]
$$

and @darij grinberg 's answer is reduced to

$$
\det A=(a-x)^n+nx(a-x)^{n-1}
$$