# I was asked to evaluate the determinant of the

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, induction, determinant

I was asked to evaluate the determinant of the $n$x$n$ matrix
$$ A=
\begin{bmatrix}
x & 2 & 2 & \cdots & 2 \\
2 & x & 2 & \cdots & 2 \\
2 & 2 & x & \cdots & 2 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
2 & 2 & 2 & \cdots & x \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
I tried starting from a 1x1 matrix to 5x5 matrix, and saw the pattern
$$\det{A}=(x-2)^{n-1}(x+2(n-1)).$$
Now I need to prove that this is the case for any nxn matrix of type A, so I tried using induction.The base case (n=1) holds.
$$A=
\begin{bmatrix}
x
\end{bmatrix}
$$
And clearly $\det{A}=x$ using both the definition of a determinant and the explicit formula above.
So now assume it holds for any $n$, and test for $n+1$.
$$\det{A}=(x-2)^n(x+2n).$$
What do I do now?

Comment: what are the eigenvalues of the matrix with all entries equal to $1?$

Comment: We aren't on eigenvalues or traces in the class yet, so I don't know.

Comment: Particular case of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2110766/calculating-determinant-with-different-numbers-on-diagonal-and-x-everywhere-else .

Comment: Also, a particular case of a different formula: Exercise 5.21 in [Darij Grinberg, *Notes on the combinatorial fundamentals of algebra*, Version of 14 September 2018](https://github.com/darijgr/detnotes/releases/tag/2018-09-14). Now that I'm looking at these two generalizations, I'm wondering if they can be combined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First subtract the last row from the first $n-1$ rows. Then add first $n-1$ columns to the last one. 
\begin{align}
\det A &= \begin{vmatrix}
x & 2 & 2 & \cdots & 2 \\
2 & x & 2 & \cdots & 2 \\
2 & 2 & x & \cdots & 2 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
2 & 2 & 2 & \cdots & x \\
\end{vmatrix} \\
&= \begin{vmatrix}
x-2 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 2-x \\
0 & x-2 & 0 & \cdots & 2-x \\
0 & 0 & x-2 & \cdots & 2-x \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
2 & 2 & 2 & \cdots & x \\
\end{vmatrix} \\
&= \begin{vmatrix}
x-2 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & x-2 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & x-2 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
2 & 2 & 2 & \cdots & x + 2(n-1) 
\end{vmatrix}\\
&= (x-2)^{n-1}(x-2(n-1))
\end{align}
The resulting determinant is lower-triangular so it is equal to the product of diagonal elements.

Answer (score 1):

We add all rows to the first one, then factor $x+2(n-1)$ from this first row, than use it (doubled) to eliminate in the other rows. With this strategy we are done quickly:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\det A
&=
\begin{vmatrix}
x & 2 & 2 & \cdots & 2 \\
2 & x & 2 & \cdots & 2 \\
2 & 2 & x & \cdots & 2 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
2 & 2 & 2 & \cdots & x \\
\end{vmatrix}
\\
&=
\begin{vmatrix}
x+2(n-1) & x+2(n-1) & x+2(n-1) & \cdots & x+2(n-1) \\
2 & x & 2 & \cdots & 2 \\
2 & 2 & x & \cdots & 2 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
2 & 2 & 2 & \cdots & x \\
\end{vmatrix}
\\
&=
(x+2(n-1))
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
2 & x & 2 & \cdots & 2 \\
2 & 2 & x & \cdots & 2 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
2 & 2 & 2 & \cdots & x \\
\end{vmatrix}
\\
&=
(x+2(n-1))
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
2-2 & x-2 & 2-2 & \cdots & 2-2 \\
2-2 & 2-2 & x-2 & \cdots & 2-2 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
2-2 & 2-2 & 2-2 & \cdots & x-2 \\
\end{vmatrix}
\\
&=
(x+2(n-1))
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
0 & x-2 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & x-2 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & x-2 \\
\end{vmatrix}
\\
&=(x+2(n-1))(x-2)^{n-1}\ .
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 1):

One way to proceed is to find the eigenvalues of $A$.

The matrix $$ A - (x-2)I = \begin{bmatrix}2 & 2 & \cdots & 2 \\ 2 & 2 & \cdots & 2 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 2 & 2 & \cdots & 2\end{bmatrix}$$ has rank $1$, which tells us that $x-2$ is an eigenvalue with multiplicity $n-1$. To find the remaining eigenvalue, there are two approaches: we can

- spot the eigenvector $\mathbf v = (1,1,\dots,1)^{\mathsf T}$, and notice that $A\mathbf v = (x + 2(n-1))\mathbf v$, or
- use the fact that $\operatorname{tr}(A) = nx$ is the sum of all the eigenvalues, and therefore the remaining eigenvalue is $nx - (n-1)(x-2) = x + 2(n-1)$.

Either way, now that we know all the eigenvalues, we conclude that $\det(A)$ is the product of all of them:
$$
   \det(A) = (x-2)^{n-1} (x + 2(n-1)).
$$