# How find this determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

\begin{vmatrix}
    2 & 4 & 4 & \dots  & 4 & 4 \\
    4 & 4 & 4 & \dots  & 4 & 4 \\
    4 & 4 & 6 & \dots  & 4 & 4 \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    4 & 4 & 4 & \dots  & 2n-2 & 4 \\
    4 & 4 & 4 & \dots  & 4 & 2n
\end{vmatrix}

I tried to get a triangular matrix, subtracting the lines, but it did not work out

Comment: see this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2110766/calculating-determinant-with-different-numbers-on-diagonal-and-x-everywhere-else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\begin{vmatrix}
    2 & 4 & 4 & \dots  & 4 & 4 \\
    4 & 4 & 4 & \dots  & 4 & 4 \\
    4 & 4 & 6 & \dots  & 4 & 4 \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    4 & 4 & 4 & \dots  & 2n-2 & 4 \\
    4 & 4 & 4 & \dots  & 4 & 2n
\end{vmatrix}
\end{eqnarray*}
Subtract the second row off all the other rows to get
\begin{eqnarray*}
\begin{vmatrix}
    -2 & 0 & 0 & \dots  & 0 & 0 \\
    4 & 4 & 4 & \dots  & 4 & 4 \\
    0 & 0 & 2 & \dots  & 0 & 0 \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & \dots  & 2n-6 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & \dots  & 4 & 2n-4
\end{vmatrix}
\end{eqnarray*}
The product on the leading diagonal is $\color{red}{-2^{n+1} (n-2)!}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
1 & 0 \\ 
2 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
2 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 4 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
1 & 2 \\ 
0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
2 & 4 \\ 
4 & 4 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
2 & 1 & 0 \\ 
2 & 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 4 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 2 & 2 \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 4 & 4 \\ 
4 & 4 & 4 \\ 
4 & 4 & 6 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
2 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
2 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 4 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 4 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
2 & 4 & 4 & 4 \\ 
4 & 4 & 4 & 4 \\ 
4 & 4 & 6 & 4 \\ 
4 & 4 & 4 & 8 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
2 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
2 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 6 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
2 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 \\ 
4 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 \\ 
4 & 4 & 6 & 4 & 4 \\ 
4 & 4 & 4 & 8 & 4 \\ 
4 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 10 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
2 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
2 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 6 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 8 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrr} 
1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrr} 
2 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 \\ 
4 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 \\ 
4 & 4 & 6 & 4 & 4 & 4 \\ 
4 & 4 & 4 & 8 & 4 & 4 \\ 
4 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 10 & 4 \\ 
4 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 12 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$